# Twitter api request for user profile image Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, twitter

I am trying to get the users profile avatar from twitter once they login but I am having trouble doing so.

```
   Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { session, error in
        if (session != nil) {
        if let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()!.userID {
                let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)
        print("the user id is \(userID)")
    let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=\(userID)"
    let params = ["profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1438634086\/avatar_normal.png"]
    var clientError : NSError?

    let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: params, error: &clientError)


        client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if (connectionError == nil) {
                var jsonError : NSError?

                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        print("i am getting some form of data")
                        print(jsonResult)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }


            }
            else {
                print("Error: \(connectionError)")
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the default twitter user information. What am I doing wrong

```
     {
"contributors_enabled" = 0;
"created_at" = "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007";
"default_profile" = 0;
"default_profile_image" = 0;
description = "The Real Twitter API. I tweet about API changes, service issues and happily answer questions about Twitter and our API. Don't get an answer? It's on my website.";
entities =     {
    description =         {
        urls =             (
        );
    };
    url =         {
        urls =             (
                            {
                "display_url" = "dev.twitter.com";
                "expanded_url" = "http://dev.twitter.com";
                indices =                     (
                    0,
                    22
                );
                url = "http://t.co/78pYTvWfJd";
            }
        );
    };
};
"favourites_count" = 27;
"follow_request_sent" = 0;
"followers_count" = 5561880;
following = 0;
"friends_count" = 47;
"geo_enabled" = 1;
"has_extended_profile" = 0;
id = 6253282;
"id_str" = 6253282;
"is_translation_enabled" = 0;
"is_translator" = 0;
lang = en;
"listed_count" = 13026;
location = "San Francisco, CA";
name = "Twitter API";
notifications = 0;
"profile_background_color" = C0DEED;
"profile_background_image_url" = "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png";
"profile_background_image_url_https" = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png";
"profile_background_tile" = 1;
"profile_banner_url" = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/6253282/1431474710";
"profile_image_url" = "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png";
"profile_image_url_https" = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png";
"profile_link_color" = 0084B4;
"profile_location" = "<null>";
"profile_sidebar_border_color" = C0DEED;
"profile_sidebar_fill_color" = DDEEF6;
"profile_text_color" = 333333;
"profile_use_background_image" = 1;
protected = 0;
"screen_name" = twitterapi;
status =     {
    contributors = "<null>";
    coordinates = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "Tue Jan 26 18:46:01 +0000 2016";
    entities =         {
        hashtags =             (
        );
        symbols =             (
        );
        urls =             (
                            {
                "display_url" = "twittercommunity.com/t/retiring-old\U2026";
                "expanded_url" = "https://twittercommunity.com/t/retiring-old-v1-streaming-api-endpoints-on-march-31st-2016/60351";
                indices =                     (
                    121,
                    144
                );
                url = "https://t.co/aNbMsNNkoY";
            }
        );
        "user_mentions" =             (
        );
    };
    "favorite_count" = 111;
    favorited = 0;
    geo = "<null>";
    id = 692055909007282176;
    "id_str" = 692055909007282176;
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_status_id" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_user_id" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str" = "<null>";
    "is_quote_status" = 0;
    lang = en;
    place = "<null>";
    "possibly_sensitive" = 0;
    "retweet_count" = 99;
    retweeted = 0;
    source = "<a href=\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>";
    text = "As announced in 2013, we're completing retirement of our v1 APIs. See our post for timeline &amp; migration information: https://t.co/aNbMsNNkoY";
    truncated = 0;
};
"statuses_count" = 3556;
"time_zone" = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)";
url = "http://t.co/78pYTvWfJd";
"utc_offset" = "-28800";
verified = 1;
```

}

When I print the data this is what I get.